# PIVOT for two fields of different data types

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a narrow table of entity IDs and Attribute identifiers.  For each row there is either a numeric value or a string.  I want to pivot out the data, but this is difficult with value fields of different types.

Currently, I'm converting the numeric value to text and then back to number again.  This has resulted in problems with formatting and I'm worried that it's inefficient.  This data will be called a lot for calculations and that means a lot of converts (not to mention loss of precision, poor maintainability, etc).

The reason we've structured the table this way is it allows for flexibility in the data being stored.  Not all entities have all attributes, and we may add more attributes in the future.  We don't want table changes to impact downstream code.  Also, we're not actually storing the Attribute name in each row but an integer ID.  For the purposes of this example I used a string rather than the numeric ID to make it easy to code/understand.

What is the proper way to pivot out fields of different data types?

Here's an example of the current table structure:

```
declare @temp table
(
    EntityID int,
    AttributeName varchar(500),
    NumberValue float,
    StringValue varchar(500),
    IsText bit
)

insert into @temp (EntityID,AttributeName,NumberValue,StringValue,IsText)
select 1,'Year',1776,null,0

insert into @temp (EntityID,AttributeName,NumberValue,StringValue,IsText)
select 1,'Note',null,'The year our country declared independence',1

insert into @temp (EntityID,AttributeName,NumberValue,StringValue,IsText)
select 2,'Year',1988,null,0

insert into @temp (EntityID,AttributeName,NumberValue,StringValue,IsText)
select 2,'Note',null,'The year Die Hard was released',1

select 
EntityID, YearNum=convert(float, [Year]), Note
from
(
select 
    EntityID,
    AttributeName,
    Value=Case when IsText=1 then StringValue else convert(varchar(500), NumberValue) end
from 
    @temp
) A
pivot
(
    Max(Value) for AttributeName in
    (
        [Year],
        Note
    )
) P
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to a `float` for the final display?  Why not just leave the data as a varchar?

Comment: @bluefeet because in my system the numbers are used in reports.  I made the data simplistic here for purposes of discussion

Answer (score 3):

Designing issues aside, I don't really see the need for using `PIVOT` unless you want your query to return a dynamic number of columns. Otherwise, you could just do something like this:

```
SELECT  EntityID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN AttributeName = 'Year' THEN NumberValue END) YearNum,
        MAX(CASE WHEN AttributeName = 'Note' THEN StringValue END) Note
FROM @temp
GROUP BY EntityID
```

Comment: isn't pivot more efficient?

Comment: @FistOfFury You would have to test it but probably not in this case

Comment: @Lamak what do you mean by "dynamic with the number of columns"?

Comment: @FistOfFury About the efficiency, it will depend, you'll need to test this solution and the `PIVOT` one, but this way we are not casting data types. About the "dynamic number of columns" I meant that if you don't know beforehand how many attributes there are, but want results for every attribute. (You'll need dynamic SQL, and `PIVOT`)

Comment: @Lamak I see.  I'm not so worried about changing the number of columns dynamically.  Mostly because don't want to bother with dynamic SQL and so I can control which attributes are output and their datatype.  Changing the view containing the PIVOT (or CASE) is not a problem.